# UIImagePickerController unloads underlying ViewControllers with memory warning

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management, uiimagepickercontroller

In my iPhone application, I've noticed that when using the UIImagePickerController it typically causes memory warnings to happen. I've read that this isn't uncommon and I know that my memory footprint is pretty small otherwise.

My problem is that when UIImagePickerController is up and it throws a memory warning, it unloads the view that presented it. After a user selects a video or image, their previously entered data is gone since the view was reloaded.

Is there any way to prevent the view from unloading, or is there a better solution? I've seen similar questions, but no good solutions.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preventing the view from unloading is probably not a good idea, since you're playing a game of chicken with the reaper (i.e. the OS could kill your app for misbehaving).

If you're concerned about losing state information, you could write that data to disk in a temporary file in your application's temp directory, and set a flag in the view/controller that says "reload me from disk".

Comment: I'll probably try something like this. The only thing I'm looking to preserve is maybe a few lines of user entered text. The memory consumed by it should be minimal.

Comment: Seems to have worked out fine. I decided to make a singleton container class to hold my data in the application instance. Thanks for the help.